# Python 2.7 Using Tkinter to concatenate a source path and filename gives error of nonetype

Tags: python-2.7

I am using Python 2.7 and imported Tkinter and TK.

What I am trying to do is use a sourced path (a directory path) and concatenate it from picking a file by opening windows explorer. This will enable the user to not have to type in a file name.

I realized I wasn't using a return and would get the following error:
    TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'NoneType' objects

After searching here for this error I found I needed to do a return. I tried to put string in the parenthesis but it doesn't' work. I am definitely missing something.

Here is a sample of my code:

```
from Tkinter import *
from Tkinter import Tk
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename

source = '\\\\Isfs\\data$\\GIS Carto\TTP_Draw_Count'  ## this a public directory path
filename = ''

filename = getFileName()  ##this part is in a different def area.

with open (os.path.join(source + filename), 'r' ) as f: ## this is were it failing.

def getFileName():

    Tk().withdraw()
    filename = askopenfilename()
    return getFileName()
```

I need to concatenate the source + filename to be used to process a csv file.

I didn't want to put all the code here since it is long and requires a csv file and custom dictionary to merge. All of that works. I hope I have put enough information in this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def getFileName():
    Tk().withdraw()
    filename = askopenfilename()
    return getFileName()
```

You aren't returning the filename that you get here. Change this to:

```
def getFileName():
    Tk().withdraw()
    filename = askopenfilename()
    return filename
```

Also note that `askopenfilename` gets the full path of the chosen file, so `source+filename` will evaluate to something like `u'\\\\Isfs\\data$\\GIS Carto\\TTP_Draw_CountC:/Users/kevin/Desktop/myinput.txt'`